# Have Flex WebServices share a common wsdl

Tags: apache-flex, wsdl

I have a flex app that loads a WSDL at runtime and shares that across several different web services I have defined. Unfortunately each call to `loadWSDL()` makes a network request for it, and while it's not really a problem due to caching it's still annoying and wasteful to have all those requests generated. Is there a simpler way to solve this problem and only make one network request?

My code is currently like:

```
var services:Array = ['service1', 'service2', ...]
for each (var name:String in services) {
  var s:WebService = ServiceLocator.getInstance().getService(name) as WebService;
  s.wsdl = wsdl;
  s.loadWSDL();
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: First off, *don't use cairngorm2*.  It's a horrible framework.  Secondly, why do you need to create a new 'service' for each call if you have exactly the same WSDL for each one?  You just need to load the WSDL once (doesn't the service do that automatically on a request?).  Seems like you're forcing it to do it manually...

Comment: @J_A_X Yeah, I agree cairngorm sucks but it's what was there and works for me after I hacked in a bunch of generalized classes. I'm not creating a new service, just loading the wsdl for each service I have defined. But since the wsdl isn't known until runtime, you have to do the loadWSDL() call manually because it won't do it by itself if you have to define the wsdl location in actionscript. Dumb feature I think.

Comment: I still don't get the issue though.  Why do you have so many services if they're all using the same WSDL? why not just have the same WebService for the same WSDL and change the operation you're calling using commands/delegates?

Comment: @J_A_X Different WebServices have different methods/operations... Throwing all the methods into one WebService is poor design... The auto-generated WSDL contains the data for all the WebServices I use. Or are you suggesting changing the 'service' parameter on the fly? That might work but I'd still need a giant base service with everything in it and I feel that it would raise exceptions anyway when it tries to validate each op belongs to the specified service.

Comment: *Again*, if the webservice WSDL is the exact same *why aren't you using commands/delegates to abstract the service and call different methods*.  What you're doing *right now* is poor design.

Answer (score 0):

If the interface of each WSDL loaded is different from each other (i.e. They have different web operations), then you have no choice than to load each interface/WSDL individually. They need to be cached on the client side so your application has means to type the attributes and functions that represent the webservices.

You would be really doing a dis-service to yourself if your loading a wsdl and your client side code is not even invoking anything on it.